# How to find the keys in the list of key, value pairs whose value is less than previous?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of tuples -

```
[(a, 4), (b, 4), (c, 3), (d, 3), (e, 3), (h, 1), (f, 3), (g, 2)]
```

and this I have got it from Counter.most_common(). How do I find the keys whose value has decreased from the previous key? Also, the key should be sorted out.

For e.g. after sorting, it should be

```
[(a, 4), (b, 4), (c, 3), (d, 3), (e, 3), (f, 3), (g, 2), (h, 1)]
```

Thus, the expectation is to get -

```
c, g, h
```

Since it has value lesser than the value it has in the previous key.

sort using keys.
then, loop key, value and compare the value from the previous. If the new value is less than previous then store it otherwise continue.

I am looking for a more efficient solution like a ready-made API of counter that can give me this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use a comprehension.

This is the result after sorting the list:

```
>>> [l[i][0] for i in range(1, len(l)) if l[i-1][1] > l[i][1]]
['c', 'g', 'h']
```

If it is not sorted just sort it with `list.sort` or `sorted` using a custom key:

```
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a list comprehension to iterate through the list and compare consecutive values.

```
li = [('a', 4), ('b', 4), ('c', 3), ('d', 3), ('e', 3), ('h', 1), ('f', 3), ('g', 2)]
res = [ li[i+1][0] for i in range(0, len(li)-1) if li[i+1][1] < li[i][1]]
print(res)
#['c', 'h', 'g']

#If you want to sort the characters.
print(sorted(res))
#['c', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: this is the same answer as Netwave's one

Comment: Ohh, I just saw that, guess my webpage wasn't refreshed with his answer!